# Grammar books recommendation

Tags: style, academic-writing, book, book-rec

I am learning to write better, and have read books such as [The Lively art of writing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451627121) and [Element of Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020530902X). I realize what I am missing is the grammar books that teaches me the different ways to construct a grammatical sentence with style.

Is there any non-fiction book out there, that is related to this? Please note this is not a duplicate of [Book recommendations for writing better technical papers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3916/book-recommendations-for-writing-better-technical-papers)

Comment: How about trying "It was the best of sentences, it was the worst of sentences?"

Comment: How did Grammar books consider duplicate of Style Manuals?

Answer (score 2):

The one grammar book that has been recommended to me by school teachers and university lecturers again and again is

- Raymond Murphy, *[English Grammar in Use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Grammar_In_Use)*

There are different editions, some "with answers" and a CD-ROM, there's an accompanying workbook, and other supplementary material. I own the second edition from 1991 without any of the gimmicks, and I can recommend it wholeheartedly. It is comprehensive, well-written, even fun to read, and covers most everything I ever wanted to know about English grammar. I still make mistakes, though ;-)

I should note that this book is not specifically concerned with literary writing and how to employ sentence structure stylistically, only in teaching you *correct* grammar.